# Adblock detection even after uninstallation of Adguard (Android)

Tags: adblock-plus

I once installed the Adguard for Android. I'm a non rooted user. I had installed the CA certificate for it.

Now I have uninstalled it and removed CA certificate completely, some websites are still displaying disable adblock. Why is this happening?

I have tried to bypass adblock detection but that didn't work either. So now I want to allow ads so that those websites work for me. How do i do that?

How do i remove those adblocking files completely which are in roots of phone even after uninstallation of Adguard?

I'm currently using Redmi note 5 pro Android phone.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The the apps use a WebView (some sort of "mini-Chrome" running inside the app then this WebView has created a cache like all browsers do. This cache my be the problem. Try to clear the cache of those apps that don't behave correct.